# Missing Google App Engine receipts in Google wallet

Tags: google-app-engine, android-pay

Since the end of April I seem to be missing receipts for my Google App Engine projects in Google Wallet.

These seem to be the smaller values, anyone have any ideas why that should be?

Answer (score 0):

Google moved over to a monthly billing cycle rather than weekly.   Did you not get the email ;-)

Extract from the email back in mid march.

> We wanted to let you know that your Google App Engine account is soon
>   transitioning to a new billing system. This change will make it even
>   easier to pay for Google App Engine each billing cycle. Among the
>   features available in the new system are:    **A monthly, rather than
>   weekly, billing cycle** Specify direct debit as a form of payment
>   Specify a primary and backup credit card as forms of payment Make a
>   payment at any time during the month This transition is scheduled to
>   be rolled out gradually after the App Engine 1.7.6 release.

Comment: Oops I missed the smaller amounts bit in your post. So maybe monthly billing is not the answer.